# "GRUB installation failed" What do I do?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, grub-efi, ubuntu-studio

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Studio version 14.04.2 (alongside my Windows 8). Everything seems to go fine during the installation until at some point this message pops up:

```
GRUB installation failed

The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader the installed system will not boot.
```

Then it says the installation crashed, and I'm taken to the Ubuntu desktop (which I imagine is the "try ubuntu" thing on the disc).

More info: I'm using a Lenovo laptop B5400 64-bit with Windows 8, and have just recently been figuring out all this business with partitions, dual OS systems and whatnot. I've disabled safe booting. I've connected to internet each time I attempted installation. I've tried the "check for corruption" option on the disk, nothing comes up so it's not that. Hitting F12 at startup and choosing to run the disc first is the right way to do this, yes? I've gone through a few answered questions but most of them don't apply to my situation, are outdated, or I don't understand the answer (many people talk about entering commands into things and I don't know when/how to do this).

Please help a confused noob out!

**Edit:** Thank you all for trying to help (and pointing me to that other topic), but the solutions there have not worked! The other asker is using a different version of Ubuntu, 12.04.3. (And it's not Ubuntu Studios, which, while it does have the /grub2 folder, it does not have /grub2-signed. And all the files do end in 64, though they have different names.) Plus, the second answer doesn't work since I'm trying to get a dual system, not wipe and repartition everything. So, that topic is of no use to me.

@shredalert: Thanks, and I hope you enjoyed your rum, but this has not worked either. I entered the commands just as you said but it comes up with something along the lines of "Errors encountered while processing yada yada yada" and it lists a bunch of things of which duplicates were found. I'm guessing since I have the latest version, there is no point in updating it and all the current files are the same as the update files. Exact same thing happens with "sudo apt-get install grub". So, the problem isn't there.

I will see if installing a normal version of Ubuntu works (rather than Ubuntu Studio... and then manually installing all the extra software. sigh). If that fails, I will try an older version. If THAT fails, I'll flip a table then do the Boot-Info thing.

...How do I remove the [duplicate]? That won't help me find answers.

Comment: May be best to see details: Post link this gives: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

On my own Laptop, Dell Inspiron 15 7577, I install dual-boot in **`UEFI`** for both Windows and Ubuntu 16.04, I have ever met the same problem during installing Ubuntu 16.04. My solution is

> > Allocate an independent **EFI Partition** when you are installing Ubuntu, its size about 500 MB, and the Ubuntu will automatically find this partition and use it as UEFI or EFI system partition, and it will help to guide system boot.
> >
> > > > Here are my disk partitions for Ubuntu installation:
> > > >         **Partition 1:** **`Ext4 journal`**, **`/`**, about 40 GB 
> > > >         **Partition 2:** **`Swap Area`**, 1GB   
> > > >         **Partition 3:** **`Ext4 journal`**, **`/boot`**, about 1GB 
> > > >         **Partition 4:** **`EFI partition`**, about 500 MB

Hope this will help you!